Powershell ISE to Include Sub Class from DLL
I am trying to create PDFs with header and footer using Powershell. I am using PowerShell v5.1. My PowerShell experience is pretty rudimentary as I usually do coding in C#/VB. Unfortunately, one of the requirements is to do this in PowerShell.  The library I am using is iTextSharp library.
I am including iTextSharp.dll in my script
Add-Type -Path "$ScriptLocation\Includes\itextsharp.dll" -ErrorAction Stop

I need to inherit the iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper class to override the OnEndPage function. Everytime I load the script into PowerShell ISE environment, I get this error: Unable to find the type [iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper]. However, the 'missing' type is part of the itextsharp.dll.
I am able to get the environment to recognize the type after the following steps:

Comment out the inherited class and the command
Run the script
Uncomment the inherit class and function

In VB.NET, it has the imports statement, sometime like this:
Imports iTextSharp.text

Is there something similar in Powershell? How can I force the PowerShell environment to recongnize the sub class (iTextSharp.text) without going through those steps I outlinged above?
My code is as follows:
Add-Type -Path "$ScriptLocation\Includes\itextsharp.dll" -ErrorAction Stop

    class PdfPageEvents : iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper {
        [string]$headerText
    
        PdfPageEvents([string]$headerText) {
            $this.headerText = $headerText
        }
    
        
        # Override OnEndPage to add header and footer
        [void] OnEndPage ([iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter]$writer, [iTextSharp.text.Document]$document) {
            $cb = $writer.DirectContent
            $pageSize = $document.PageSize
    
            # Add header
            $header = New-Object iTextSharp.text.Paragraph($this.headerText, New-Object iTextSharp.text.Font([iTextSharp.text.Font]::ARIAL, 12))
            $header.Alignment = [iTextSharp.text.Element]::ALIGN_CENTER
            $headerTable = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable(1)
            $headerTable.TotalWidth = $pageSize.Width - $document.LeftMargin - $document.RightMargin
            $headerTable.AddCell($header)
            $headerTable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, $document.LeftMargin, $pageSize.Height - $document.TopMargin + 15, $cb)
   
        }
    }
    
    $pdfDocument = New-Object iTextSharp.text.Document([iTextSharp.text.Rectangle]::new([iTextSharp.text.PageSize]::A4.Height, [iTextSharp.text.PageSize]::A4.Width))
                
    $fileStream = New-Object -TypeName IO.FileStream -ArgumentList ($FileOutputName, [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
    $pdfWriter = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter]::GetInstance($pdfDocument, $filestream)
    [iTextSharp.text.FontFactory]::RegisterDirectories()
    $pdfDocument.Open()
    $paragraph = New-Object -TypeName iTextSharp.text.Paragraph
    
    $headerString = "Header Text"
    $pdfWriter.PageEvent = [PdfPageEvents]::new("$headerString")
    $paragraph.add("blah blah blah")
    $pdfDocument.Add($paragraph)
    $pdfDocument.Close()


It's a long standing bug, use one of the alternatives of the link. Best approach is to create a module and load your dll using the RequiredAssemblies from the psd1 manifest.

As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is no longer actively developed and there are reasons not to use it (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is Visual Studio Code with its PowerShell extension.
